# Printing Python version in output

Tags: python

How can I print the version number of the current Python installation from my script?

Answer (score 786):

Try

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

This prints the full version information string. If you only want the python version number, then [Bastien Léonard's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252163/printing-python-version-in-output/1252175#1252175) is the best. You might want to examine the full string and see if you need it or portions of it.

Answer (score 268):

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

This prints something like

> 3.7.2

Answer (score 74):

You can retrieve the Python version using various methods, depending on your specific needs and context. Here are some different ways to print the Python version:

1. Using the sys module:

   ```
   import sys

   print("Python version")
   print(sys.version)
   print("Version info.")
   print(sys.version_info)
   ```
2. Using the platform module:

   ```
   import platform

   print(platform.python_version())
   ```
3. From the command line (Terminal or Command Prompt):

   ```
   python --version
   ```
4. Using the sysconfig module (for more detailed information):

   ```
   import sysconfig

   print(sysconfig.get_python_version())
   ```
5. Using the platform module (detailed version information):

   ```
   import platform

   print(platform.python_build())
   ```
6. In an interactive Python shell:

   ```
   >>> import sys
   >>> sys.version
   ```

These methods will provide you with different levels of detail about the Python version currently installed on your system.

Comment: Nice and simple!  I would recommend the latter method because older version of Python do not support the "--version" flag.  Plus, the less typing for me, the better.

Comment: No it should not be the answer, because Thomas specifically asked "...in the output?". He wasn't asking how to discover which version he had installed, he was asking how to include that information into a 'print' statement.

Comment: The command must be executed in the OS console, not in the Python console. In a fresh console it returns the version of the base conda environment, which can be different from the environment used by the IDE/script.

Answer (score 44):

```
import sys
```

expanded version

```
sys.version_info  
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=2, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

specific

```
maj_ver = sys.version_info.major  
repr(maj_ver) 
'3'
```

or

```
print(sys.version_info.major)
'3'
```

or

```
version = ".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3]))
print(version)
'3.2.2'
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using jupyter notebook Try:

```
!python --version
```

If you are using terminal Try:

```
 python --version
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of having a one-liner :

```py
print(__import__('sys').version)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
python -V
```

or

```
python --version
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have tuple type of the version, you can use the following:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version_tuple())

print(type(platform.python_version_tuple()))
# <class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you specifically want to output the python version from the program itself, you can also do this. Uses the simple python version printing method we know and love from the terminal but does it from the program itself:

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system('python -V') # can also use python --version
```

Comment: Recent Ubuntu versions don’t have a `python` executable, so this would fail.

Comment: You can have multiple Python versions - the first one on the PATH environment variable wins - On my current project print(sys.version) gives me 3.11.4 and os.system('python -V') give me 3.10.11