# How to change the default Python interpreter in Sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, anaconda

I am currently using the Anaconda python distribution for my project (NOT the anaconda plugin, they have the same name, but the one I am using includes Numpy, IPython, etc. It is kinda confusing). So I want to change the default python (v3.3) to the one in Anaconda (v2.7.6), in that case I will be able to use the libraries embedded in Anaconda. I tried to put a new script under Tool > Build System > New Build System.

```
{
"path": "/home/username/anaconda/bin",
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

But it failed, the sublime is still using the default interpreter:

```
>>>print (sys.version)
3.3.0 (default, Jun 12 2013, 17:01:35) 
[GCC 4.7.2]
>>> print (sys.executable)
python3
>>> print (sys.path)
['/opt/sublime_text', '/opt/sublime_text/python3.3.zip', '/home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages']
```

So my question is quite simple (but hard enough for one who doesn't know):
How to change this default python interpreter to the one I want;

Comment: It looks like you're using an internal console. Changing the build system isn't going to change Sublime Text 3's personal version of Python. Can you try executing [a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252163/printing-python-version-in-output) to test the version number in interpreted files instead?

Comment: You are right, I was using the internal console. I just create the script and run it using "ctrl + B", and the output tells me the version is 2.7.6 and the version of python is under /home/myname/anaconda/bin/python (which is exactly what I am expecting for). But I am not sure how that happen cause I am no longer use the new added "Build System" but the default one.

Comment: Since I can use the my ideal 2.7.6 python to execute my code, I think the only problem left is how to use this 2.7.6 python interpreter as my interactive console and not 3.3 that is running right now. Many thanks!

Comment: Great! You might like SublimeREPL. https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL

Answer (score 6):

You can get it working by distinguishing the name of python.

For example change

```
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

to

```
C:\Python27\python2.exe
```

Change your environment variables to reference this change. Type python2 in cmd to confirm its working.

And then you should be able to reference this from your build hotkey.

```
{
"path": "/home/username/anaconda/bin",
"cmd": ["python2", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Extremely Simple Method :**

You can get [sublime-text-conda](https://github.com/mandeep/sublime-text-conda) via the package manager: `Ctrl`+`shift`+ `P`
Serach for **conda**, once installed, you need to activate or create the environments within sublimetext to change environment: `Ctrl`+`shift`+ `P`, and type: **conda** :

[image: conda functions in context]

From here, when you build the env, you can select conda if not selected:

[image]

** I've noticed that if I switched to a conda env form package control, and selected a different build system, then the build system doesn't switch back when you re-select conda via package control, might wanna check this if you switch between build systems.