# python matplotlib converter

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a program that takes data and plots it via matplotlib. It works no problem on one computer but on the other I get the error:

```
TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py", line 125, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/queue.py", line 172, in get raise Empty queue.Empty
```

what can I do to get a cairo.Context converter?

Comment: Could you provide the corresponding source?

Comment: (tkintergood.py:6547): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

Comment: @infinitezero does that help?

Comment: Not really. I meant the source code. Anyway, you can check, whether you have the same version installed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252163/printing-python-version-in-output