# Dictionaries on Python not getting stored as assigned

Tags: python, python-2.x

So have just started dictionaries in Python (using Spyder if that helps)...
basically made a dictionary called t, but the values don't get stored in the order i have assigned

```
t={'first':'a','second':'b','third':'c'}
print t
for i in t :
    print t[i]
```

the values in t get stored as {'second': 'b', 'third': 'c', 'first': 'a'} and get assigned as such?!
whats going on here?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered until CPython 3.6 began maintaining insertion order as an implementation detail and Python 3.7+ added it as a formal specification. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: looks like python 2 by the looks of the print statement without ( ) -

Comment: You can verify by  using the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252163/printing-python-version-in-output

Comment: the version im using is 2.7.17.. should i upgrade to python 3.7.. am not a power user just want to learn the language