# ModuleNotFoundError when importing from a ROS package

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, ros

I have use a robot simulator which only works on ROS Indigo. I also have to use Tensorflow and Jupyter Notebook so I have created a virtual environment with Python3.6.

I want to import a file from the simulator package in a notebook. So after I source bin/activate for the virtualenv, I source devel/setup.bash from my catkin workspace. But even after doing this I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8370e76446ee> in <module>
----> 1 import herbpy

~/my_workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/herbpy/__init__.py in <module>
     33 for __execfile in __execfiles:
     34     with open(__execfile, 'r') as __fh:
---> 35         exec(__fh.read())
     36     del __fh
     37     del __execfile

~/my_workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/herbpy/__init__.py in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'herb'
```

I tried running a python file importing this module (while in the environment). It only ran with python2. But with python2, I can't use Tensorflow.

How do I import this file in my notebook?

Comment: You may need to explicitly add the module to your path. `import sys` and then `sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")`

Comment: @VarunNayak Doing that brought up the same error for other modules. After adding those modules explicitly. it eventually gave me syntax for a file in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. I don't understand how can it give a syntax error inside the notebook, while it works perfectly fine otherwise.

Comment: Do you have to use python3? Ros indigo was designed on-top of python2. If you want guaranteed native ros targeting python3, ros noetic for ubuntu 20 is available, if you don't have to use ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things. Remember that you can specify the version of python to run via the [shebang in your script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take?rq=1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  # For "both" versions, not recommended for ros
#!/usr/bin/env python2 # For ros, to access the python/pip packages only installed for py2
#!/usr/bin/env python3 # For python3 code, to avoid that 'python' usually selects py2
```

You can call different python executables from launch files this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- py3_ex.launch -->
    <node name="call_py3" pkg="my_new_pkg" type="call_py3.py" output="screen">
    </node>
</launch>
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# call_py3.py
# Try to print out the python version
import sys
import platform
#import rospy

#rospy.init_node("call_py3");
print("\n\nPython Version:\n")
print(sys.version)
print(platform.python_version())
print("\n\n")
#rospy.spin()
```

The above script will run python3 code [(printing the version number)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1252163/6069586), including tensorflow. The issue is that it, on trying to `import rospy` on py3 instead of py2, it won't find some of it's dependencies (such as rospkg) and give a fatal error.

To get around this, (assuming you don't switch to Ubuntu 20 + ROS Noetic, with native py3 support, or just use py2), you can call py3 scripts from your py2 ros node, such as with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) and piping. Or better yet, [socket udp](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) send over localhost your data/images/results/inputs, that might be the simplest way. To go this way, (and it works!) make a `import socket` udp connection to a localhost (127.0.0.1) random port (ex 5050), on both sides. Launch both scripts. Your py3 script can't `import rospy` but it can import ros msgs: `from sensor_msgs.msg import Image`. You can find a means to [serialize it](https://github.com/uos/rospy_message_converter) (there's multiple ways to turn a py obj into string and back).

A more painful way to setup python3 (but should be easier to use after) is to somehow replace the python2 packages to use ros with python3. There are a bunch of guides out there, and plenty of people who've ran into issues posted on SO.